# What's the meaning of "I may have lost a little bit of this year" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, translation, sentence-meaning

Does it mean that I lost a part of my idealism this year, or it says without a vision, my idealism would has been less? which one?

I am really glad I wrote a vision because I think I would be a lot more negative right now if I hadn’t done that. My vision reminded me of why I am doing this, and what I am trying to accomplish. It’s kind of forced me to hold on to all that idealism that I may have lost a little bit of this year.”

Comment: Have you missed a word out of the header of this question? Reading the body of the question I think it should read "I may have lost a bit of _vision_ this year",  but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the terms are all together in the last sentence and work there I don't see them referring to others in the previous ones.

> *lost a little bit of this year*

is modifying

> *all that idealism*

If it helps, the vision can be thought of as a manifesto or a written plan. They are glad it is written down.